# Preferred Workflow for Ruby-YAML interaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, yaml

I have just started working on a project where there is a lot of interaction between Ruby and 5-6 levels deep YAML files. Since Ruby will respond with `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` when you are trying to access a key that doesn't exist there are lots of methods with the following setup:

```
def retrieve_som_data(key1, key2)
  results = []
  if data(key1, key2)
    if data_set_2(key, key2)["my_key"]
      results = data_set_2(key, key2)["my_other_key"]
    end
  end
  return results.clone
end
```

This looks horrible, so I am looking at a way to refactor it. I have tried working on a version where I would replace a method like this:

```
def data(key1, key2)
  if data = names_data(key1)
    return data[key2]
  end
end
```

with this instead:

```
def data(key1, key2)
  names_data(key1).fetch(key2)
end
```

This raises a more specific error `KeyError` which can than be rescued and acted on in any method calling `.data()`, but this also doesn't seem like a good solution readability wise.

I'd love to get some input on how you are handling situations where you are trying to access `YAML_DATA[key][key1][key2][key3][key4]` and take into account that any of the provided keys could hit something thats `nil`.

What are your preferred workflows for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Add a minimal example of input data that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using rails, they've added a method, `try` to Object. For nil objects this will always return nil, rather than throwing so you could do something along the lines of this:

```
def get_yaml_obj(yaml_data, key1, key2, key3)
  yaml_data.try(:[], key1).try(:[], key2).try(:[], key3)
end
```

Or if you have an arbitary number of keys:

```
def get_data(yaml_data, keys)
  keys.each do |key|
    yaml_data = yaml_data.try(:[], key)
  end
  yaml_data
end
```

Comment: Definately a better option. Thx for your respond.